# MIMIC-III: Why is the time stamp of prescription only "per day"?

Tags: mimic-iii

How can I tell the exact time of prescription, or the start of medications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A critical care physician makes a prescription during morning rounds. That does not mean that any change is impossible but it initiates a logistic process to obtain the medication on the right spot. We prescribe per 24h, but changes are possible ad hoc.
Cheers
Sven

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the start of medications, MIMIC-III doesn't provide the actual start of medications. This means if a medicine is recorded as having been prescribed, there is no guarantee that it has been taken by the patient.